# Cutting down on the number of public classes in my .NET application?

Tags: .net

I'm concerned that a lot of the classes in my application are `public`. I figure that the majority of them don't need to be.

Are there any tools that can analyse my project (or the binary) and tell me which classes can safely be made `internal`?

Comment: How would the tool know that?  It would have to be a mind-reader, since it doesn't know how you intend to use the classes.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: basically by tracking which classes are used outside an assembly; any dependency analyzer can do that.

Comment: No, I'm not writing a library; I'm writing an application.

Comment: Okay, make them all internal then.  It really doesn't matter.

Comment: Right, so if I'm writing an *application*, is there ever any need to have public classes? Does (e.g.) WPF databinding, etc., require that stuff be public?

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe: most of us split our layers into separate assemblies; the logic will go in one assembly, the UI will go in another. If you're crossing assemblies, your classes must be public.

Comment: @Randolpho: I know that. My question: do any of the classes *in the application* have to be public? I'll open another question for that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/)  will make sugestions, and much more , does a lot of code analysis.

Comment: But does it have a report (I'm thinking FxCop- or ReSharper-like) that specifically says: "these classes do not appear to be used outside this application, and can probably be made internal"?

Comment: yes, under the encapuslation section of the CQL queries, is give you a list of your classes the could be changed 'Types that could be declared as private".

This is an old post but the author explains what he is try to do.

http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2007/10/31/optimal-encapsulation.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) and the [Visual Studio Dependency Graph generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409453.aspx).

**Edit:**
That said, I think Kim Jing's deleted post had an excellent suggestion: although the tools will tell you what classes are and aren't used outside your library, it's really something you should do manually wearing your Solution Architect hat.

Answer (score 1):

NDepend is a good place to start. http://www.ndepend.com/

However, in an ideal world having specific client interfaces `public interface` I think is the way to move forward as these would be your "pinch points".

Interface segregation principle -

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle

Of course you can always find out in a non-production environment by making everything non public. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are looking to make classes internal suggests that you should consider breaking the solution up into a library containing the classes that you want hidden away, and an *interface* containing the classes that you would leave public